# How to get reviews on a page with Google Places API

Tags: php, google-places-api

I am kinda stuck with the reviews part of the API. On the home page of a website people can fill in there restaurant, after that they will be redirected to a different page where the website shows the customer some information about there restaurant including a picture that they have on google there location in google maps and there last 5 reviews. But I don't know how to implement the review part so that i can also get 5 reviews on the page together with te image and google maps location.

I have already tried to implement it to get reviews on the page of course. But I just don't understand how to do it. And haven't figured it out yet.

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Trial Form
*/

$placeId = $_GET['pid'];
$placeUrl = API_GATEWAY_HOST . '/place-details?' . http_build_query([
    'placeid' => $placeId,
    'fields' => 'photo,formatted_address,geometry,name',
    'language' => pll_current_language(),
]);
$response = wp_remote_get($placeUrl);
$place = json_decode($response['body'], true);

if ($place['status'] !== 'OK') {
status_header( 404 );
nocache_headers();
include(get_query_template( '404' ));
die();
}

$lat = $place['result']['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$lng = $place['result']['geometry']['location']['lng'];
$photoSrc = (isset($place['result']['photos'])) ?
API_GATEWAY_HOST . '/places-photo?'. http_build_query([
    'photoreference' => $place['result']['photos'][0]['photo_reference'],
    'maxwidth' => '1600',
])
: 'https://soconnect-website- 
uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2018/11/placeholder-image.png';
$mapSrc = API_GATEWAY_HOST . '/staticmap?' . http_build_query([
    'center' => $lat . ',' . $lng,
    'markers' => 'color:red|'. $lat . ',' . $lng,
    'size' => '640x220',
    'language' => pll_current_language(),
]);
$name = $place['result']['name'];
$address = $place['result']['formatted_address'];

get_header();
?>
<main class="home trial-form">
    <div class="page page--full">
        <div class="venue-photo" style="background-image: url('<? 
=$photoSrc?>')"></div>
        <div class="page__content">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="grid-unit--6 description">
                    <?php echo get_field('Article'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class='grid-unit--4 form'>
                    <div class="static-map" style="background-image: 
url('<?=$mapSrc?>')"></div>
                    <div class="form--big form--white">
                        <p class="name"><?=$name?></p>
                        <p><?= get_field('Form')['description'] ?></p>
                        <?php
                        gravity_form(
                                get_field('Form')['id'],
                                false,
                                false,
                                false,
                                ['address' => $address, 'location' => 
$name]
                        );
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
<?
get_footer();
```

I hope that someone can help me solve this for me, and could help me implement the parts that are needed to get the reviews on this page. It does not really matter where they come at the moment as long as it works because thats the problem at the moment.

Comment: What errors, if any, are you getting?

Comment: None! Everything works fine, it displays the background image and the location with google maps. But what my problem is, is that I just can not figure out how to also display the reviews on the page.